# Load aurora data to s3 using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Am trying to load the data from Aurora(MySQL) to s3 I have done necessary configuration and able to run below query successfully

```
SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE S3 's3-us-west-2://my-s3-bucket/sample_data' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but when I am trying to  do the same thru **stored procedure** but its giving below syntax error even for saving stored procedure.

```
'S3' is not valid at this position use 'text' or "text"
```

**Note:** Same error giving in normal plain query but its working as expected and saved data to s3.

am I missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar problem and I resolved it by using prepared sql statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Example:

```
set @l_sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE S3 ''s3-us-west-2://my-s3-bucket/sample_data'' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n'' ';     
prepare stmt from @l_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect, BTW am unable to execute [LOAD DATA FROM S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html) any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to help you, because I have used this command outside of DB so far (in shell scripts, python code and so on)